# Passing flags to bash script

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I have the following script to call a node.js script:

```
declare -a years=(
  '2011'
  '2012'
  '2013'
  '2014'
  '2015'
  '2016'
)

  for year in "${years[@]}"
  do
    gps --type=CNPJ --format=XLS --identification=??? --password=???? --competence=${year} --output="THE Identification - $year"
  done
```

And i would like it to call:

```
bash gps.sh --identification=1234567890 --password=123456
```

Is it possible? Currently i need change every time the file and call it, and passing as a flag would me much faster to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
--identification=??? --password=????
```

by

```
"$1" "$2"
```